ESTA unnecessary anxiety
I am planning a trip to the US with my family and partner and we're all from ESTA-eligible countries, so we all submitted our applications, which were approved. However, there are two "issues" that are giving me what may very well be unnecessary anxiety, so hoping to check it out on here.

My mother, in the fields asking for place of residence (not the address while in US), has put the country in the country field, but also in the state/region field, instead of the region within the country she's living in. It may very well be completely not important at all, but hopefully not grounds for an ESTA revision/revocation later on or refusal at the border?

My partner is a dual national, so she has disclosed both nationalities. In the field asking whether she had any passports issued by another country, she put the details of the expired passport that she was I in the process of renewing at the time, as that was the most recent info that was technically in her possession. Note that this is not the passport that will be linked to her ESTA. The ESTA is primarily linked to her other nationality, whose passport is valid.


A couple of days after submitting the ESTA application, the embassy told her the new passport is ready (note this is done via an online tracking system, where you log in and check whether it's ready or not, so it may have been ready before the ESTA submission). And a couple of days after that, the ESTA was approved. Now, due to embassy processing times, of course the issue date of this new passport may be earlier than the date of ESTA application (we haven't picked the passport up yet). So the 2nd nationality passport number on the ESTA would not have been strictly speaking the "most recent one". She however didn't have the "most recent passport" in her possession yet, so she couldn't have put the most recent info. Putting "unknown" seemed like a bad idea as we did know "some" details, just not the technically most recent ones. Could this cause any issue?

I didn't include any address of stay in the US as I wasn't sure yet where we'd be staying. I can update the field, but read online or people whose ESTA was revoked after they updated that field. I imagine that disclosing the address at the border, if asked, would be enough and not raise suspicion?


Nothing can be guaranteed but you should be able to relax.  Have the evidence for the missing of incorrect data ready but don't present it unless asked.  Just answer any questions politely and accurately.

Relax. The ESTA was approved and nobody will ever look at any of the information you entered again, much less try to validate it somehow.  The formatting of home address and the details of passports you're not going to use to enter the US are particularly inconsequential; remember, there are lots of countries that don't even have "states".
If you're asked something at the border, answer it honestly.  That's it.

nobody will ever look at any of the information you entered again I would generally agree with that - certainly 99.99% of the time. If there is some other problem that raises questions, then I would imagine somebody would go back to review all prior paperwork. But that is unlikely.

Surely the vast, vast majority of countries don't have states, right? I would expect having states is the exception.

@terdon They may not call them states, but most countries do have an administrative division larger than cities: provinces, prefectures, cantons, etc.

@lambshaanxy: Even if they do, though, it is not necessarily used in the same way – e.g. my country is small enough that while we do have administrative regions above cities, we practically never include them as part of a delivery address (unless faced with an address form made in the US that assumes the state field is mandatory, and then we just duplicate the city name most of the time).

@user1686 Yup, that's why I said it doesn't really matter how you enter your home address.  I used to enter Country Singapore, State Singapore, City Singapore when living in (surprise!) Singapore, a city-state with no divisions of any kind.
